# need xpath expression which contains break in the label

Tags: xpath

```
@FindBy( how = How.XPATH, 
         using = "//div[@class='dynamic-main-content']
                     //div[label[text()='Number of At Fault Claim Free Years']]
                        /select" ) 
        private WebElement _faultClaimFreeYearsDropDown;
```

In the actual HTML there is a break in the label text. How should I write the XPATH?

Comment: @user569254: If by "break" you mean a `br` element, then there isn't a **text node** with the 'Number of At Fault Claim Free Years' string value. Don't you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also, don't use `[text()='the text']`, use `[normalize-space(.)='the text']`. Using `.` rather than `text()` makes your code resilient to things such as comments (or element markup) appearing within the text you are matching.

Comment: Thanks a lot that works like magic and gives me whole lot of fresh ideas.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a line-break (carriage return and/or line feed) or additional whitespace in the label text you could use `normalize-space()` on the `label`'s `text()`:

`//div[@class='dynamic-main-content']//div[label[normalize-space(.)='Number of At Fault Claim Free Years']]/select`

Comment: //div[@class='dynamic-main-content']//div[label[normalize-space(text())='Number of At Fault Claim Free Years']]/select - this does not work here. I am tryign to chk it using view xpather and it does not show me any results

Comment: It would be helpful to have a sample of your HTML. It is hard to tell you why if we don't know what it is selecting against. The XPATH you provided might have other issues besides the line breaks. Adjusting for line breaks will still leave those issues to deal with.